# Text typed in text box shown in URL bar / generating profile page

Tags: html, css

Text typed in text box are shown in the URL bar including the password. Any way to fix this for it not to show on the URL bar? Tried Googling but results were irrelevant.

It looks like this:

```
login_page.html?email=asdasdasd&password=asdasdasd
```

Comment: please include relevant code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably used `method="get"` in your form like this:

```html
<form method="get">
```

Try using the post method instead like this:

```
<form method="post">
```

Then, if you're using PHP, for example, on the server side to get the inputs of your form, you'll have to make sure you're looking for the super global `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Comment: Ohh wow, thank you! can I also use this on my registration form?? instead of method="put"?

Comment: it really depends on what you're using on the server side to receive the data... you may want to post it as a new question, as it's not necessarily related to this one... just make sure you always include relevant code and what you have tried to make it work... good luck!